# (A+B')' (A'+B) convert to product of sums

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic

(A+B')' (A'+B) convert this to PoS (product of sums ) expression using De Morgan's law

i can do (A+B') (A'+B) one but i can not convert (A+B')' (A'+B) because it has single over bars on more than one variable.please help me

Comment: i can do (A+B') (A'+B) one but i can not convert (A+B')' (A'+B) because it has single over bars on more than one variable.please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(A+B')'(A'+B)    starting expression
(A'B)(A'+B)      De Morgan on (A+B')'
A'BA'+A'BB       distributive property
A'A'B+A'BB       commutative property
A'B+A'BB         XX=X on A'A'B
A'B+A'B          XX=X on A'BB
A'B              X+X=X on A'B+A'B
```

I don't know that I'd call that "product of sums" form but it is the simplest equivalent expression. If you really insist on product of sums then we can run the `X+X=X` rule in reverse:

```
A'B               starting expression
(A'+A')B          X=X+X on A'
(A'+A')(B+B)      X=X+X on B
```

Comment: (A'B)(A'+B)  how can we apply distributive law to this  distributive law is like this  (A+'B)(A'+B) but (A'B)(A'+B) has different operation for first term

Comment: @doly You are distributing (A'B). The distributive law is really X(Y+Z) = XY + XZ. Your version, (W+X)(Y+Z) = WY + WZ + XY + XZ is actually just the basic law applied twice. I suppose when I do (A'B)(A'+B) = A'BA' + A'BB I am using two laws: first, the distributive law; then, the associative law.